# Call helpers from within helpers

Tags: node.js, helper, express

I'm working on this web app, using Expressjs, and I feel the need for a feature that Microsoft's Razor view engine provides.

Razor allows one to call helpers from within other helpers. 
   In Expressjs, the helpers' scope does not extend to the helpers themselves when they are called from a view.

Is there a sollution for this? I would like to not have to pass the helpers to the view as parameters, or have to require the helper's file.

Thanks in advance

Example:

I have

```
app.helpers({ TextBoxHelper: require('./TextBox.js') });
app.helpers({ CharCounter  : require('./CharCounter.js'  ) });
```

in my server. When I'm rendering a view, I use jshtml view engine and to call a helper, I just have to do the following:

```
@TextBoxHelper()    //I can do this because all helpers are present in this scope
```

When the helper is called, it exits the view scope, and there will be no access to the other helpers there.

Now, I would like this helper "TextBox" to call "CharCounter". This second helper, is supposed to be called by several other helpers, so, it would be great if I could just call it from the helpers' ".js" files, without having to require the script, or send it as a parameter.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you are trying to do? Also be aware that helpers and dynamicHelpers got removed in 3.x.

Comment: I added an example at the bottom of the question, Pickels. When you say version 3.x, are you referring to Express? o.O

Comment: I mean Express.js 3.x. In the new version you just have res.locals. So if you want a helper in 3.x you just do `app.locals.myHelper = function () { }` for a global helper or `res.locals.myHelper = function () { }` route specific helper.

Answer (score 0):

I would just bundle all the helpers into one object. That way you can use `this.someHelper()`.

```
var helpers = {
  first: function () {
    console.log('first');
    helpers.second();
  },

  second: function () {
    console.log('second');
  }
};


helpers.first();
```

If `this` isn't what you want it to be you can always easily change it in Javascript.

Comment: Well, in a way, the helpers are already all bundled and available for the View Engine. The problem is that, if I'm working inside one of the helpers at a given time, I don't have access to the others.

Sure I could pass that helpers object as a parameter to the helper I'm calling, and it would have access to them all. I was just wondering if there was a more native way of doing that.